# Angular enable/disable virtual keyboard via a checkbox

Tags: angular, virtual-keyboard

I use material virtual keyboard on my form https://github.com/protacon/ng-virtual-keyboard. its work pretty

```html
Module.ts
---------
import { NgVirtualKeyboardModule } from '@protacon/ng-virtual-keyboard';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ........
        NgVirtualKeyboardModule,
        ........
    ],
    
    
layout.html
---------
<input class="form-control" type="number" ng-virtual-keyboard ng-virtual-keyboard-layout="numeric" ng-virtual-keyboard-placeholder="Property Name"/>
```

Is it possible to enable/disable virtual keyboard in my form via a checkbox?

Comment: have it enclosed in a div and set it to hidden on checkbox click

Comment: if I hide the div, virtual keyboard continues to use input bindings keypress, keydown etc

Comment: okay then i guess you might need to use a if sort of thing remove that whole element from the place use if checked without the virual board else have the virtual board